# Task.wait in task array

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to execute the line completed after all the tasks completed.I thought Task.WaitAll(tasks) will take care but after executing callback method my completed line gets executed.Is there a way to block the main thread untill the Task aray completes it.

Taskpprcessor.Batchstart(definition)

```
public void BatchStart(List<TaskDefinition> definition)
        {
            int i = 0;
            tasks = new Task[definition.Count];
            definition.ForEach((a) =>
            {

                tasks[i] = Task<TaskResult>.Factory.StartNew(() => (TaskResult)a.MethodTocall.DynamicInvoke(a.ARguments));
                tasks[i].ContinueWith(task => RunTaskRetObjResultIns((Task<TaskResult>)task, a.CompleteMethod));    
                i++;

            });
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
Console.WriteLine("completed");
}
```

Comment: Don't increment an outside variable in a closure. IE, don't define `i` outside of a closure block, and then increment it inside of your `foreach` lambda. That's a fun way to get weird and hard to debug errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

```
public void BatchStart(List<TaskDefinition> definition)
{
    Task.WaitAll(
        definition.Select
            (a => Task<TaskResult>.Factory.StartNew(
                () => (TaskResult)a.MethodTocall.DynamicInvoke(a.ARguments)).ContinueWith(task => RunTaskRetObjResultIns((Task<TaskResult>)task, a.CompleteMethod))
            ).ToArray()
        );
    Console.WriteLine("completed");
}
```

I think the problem is that ContinueWith returns a new Task, and that's the one you want to Wait for. You're waiting for the original tasks but not the continuation.

Comment: Thanks dominic It works you are correct. To avoid overload I am using dynamic.invoke is it a good practice.Thanks sircodesalot I am need call back result thats why i took task.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use PLINQ, as in:

```
List<Object> items = new List<Object>();

items.AsParallel().ForAll(obj => { 
    // Write whatever the object is to the string, but do it parallelly
    Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString()); 
});

Conosle.WriteLine("Done");
```

That will execute all of your tasks parallelly, and then return when complete.